# How to limit the number of duplicates returned in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

If I have a table that is `Names`, which has just first name and last name as columns and I want to select everything (first and last names), but limit the number of repeated first names to 3. So for example,

| First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- |
| John | Smith |
| John | Doe |
| Ryan | Green |
| Mike | Williams |
| John | Thompson |
| John | Brown |

becomes

| First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- |
| John | Smith |
| John | Doe |
| Ryan | Green |
| Mike | Williams |
| John | Thompson |

How do I construct a query to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.  For instance:

```
select firstname, lastname
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by firstname order by rand()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Note:  This returns random rows for each name.  You can control which rows you get using the `order by` clause.